# Data is storing in computer through application but not in smartphone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was building an application and wanted to get data through text file. when i put the location of any folder of computer then it is working properly but when i changed the location and use that app with android smart phone it doesn't save txt file in mobile's internal storage or sdcard.

How can i save .txt file in mobile internal storage?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class click2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static bool mobileSD;
    public static string saveLocation;

    public void onclick()
    {
        // in order to save at sdcard, make it 'true'
        mobileSD = true;
        if (mobileSD == false) { saveLocation = "d:/"; }
        else { saveLocation = "/sdcard/Download/"; }

        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@saveLocation + 1 + ".txt", true))
            {
                file.Write("a");
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the 1 for in the code? `new System.IO.StreamWriter(@saveLocation + 1 + ".txt", true))`

Comment: 1 is file name. it will be better if it change to 2 in save the data of next attempt

Answer (score 0):

Save Data in your  `Application.persistentDataPath`

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data

First : 
Write Your Data when you start the app. 
Second: when you want to load your Data 
Check if the File Existed in the `Application.persistentDataPath`
and if true you can read it normally, if not write your default settings in It.

Comment: Thank you for your response. this is a dummy of my program. it is also not working like that. i don't have to load data. i just want to save my app data( button response) in .txt format. This working in unity during checking with system location but i does't work when i built app to mobile phone with internal storage location. In some of tutorials i checked, many people used same code to do that as well. Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try This code and Customize it depending on Your Requirements :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public string DATA_PATH = "player.json";
    void Start()
    {
        GamePalyer p = new GamePalyer();
        p.Id = 1;
        p.Name="John Smith";
        p.Score = 100;
        Debug.Log("Starts Saving");
        SaveDataToFile(p);
        ReadData();
    }

    public void SaveDataToFile(GamePalyer _player)
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + DATA_PATH;
        Debug.Log("Saving At : "+ filePath);
        string savedData = JsonUtility.ToJson(_player);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, savedData);
    }

    public void ReadData()
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + DATA_PATH;
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText(filePath); ;
            GamePalyer player = JsonUtility.FromJson<GamePalyer>(data);
            Debug.Log(player.Id);
            Debug.Log(player.Name);
            Debug.Log(player.Score);
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GamePalyer
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public float Score;
}
```